# VBA copy/paste loop not pulling anything

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I've only been at VBA for about 2 weeks so I need some assistance. I have a loop setup to copy 7 cells across on workbook (A), then paste them vertically in a column on workbook (B). For some reason the code is working but will not paste any data... I've been trying to troubleshoot for a while now with no luck.
Here is a screenshot of the sheet I'm copying data from.
[image: Workbook (A)]

Here is a screenshot of the workbook I'm pasting too.
[image: Workbook (B)]

```
Sub pullSecEquipment()

Dim path As String
Dim ThisWB As String
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim shtDest As Worksheet

Dim Filename As String
Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim CopyRng As Range, DestRng As Range
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim destLRow As Integer

Dim UpdateDate As String

ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Dim selectedFolder


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    selectedFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

End With

path = selectedFolder

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False



Set shtDest = Workbooks("GPnewchapterTEST2.xlsm").Worksheets("START")

'clear content of destination table
shtDest.Rows("8:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents


Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls*", vbNormal)

If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
        'MsgBox Filename
        
        '''''
        'SEC
        '''''
        
        If InStr(Filename, "Equipment") <> 0 Then
            
            '''
            '' Equipment Hours
            '''
            Dim range1 As Range
            Set range1 = Range("E:K")
            
            
        If shtDest.Name Like "*-*" Then

            'last row
            destLRow = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            '1st row
            lRow = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="EQUIPMENT DESCRIPTION", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
            

            Dim i As Integer
            For i = lRow To destLRow
            
            Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 5).Address, Cells(i, 11).Address)
            Set DestRng = shtDest.Range("O" & shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            
            CopyRng.Copy
            DestRng.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear Clipboard
            
            i = i + 2
            
            Next i
          

        End If
        End If
        
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

MsgBox "Done!"
```

End Sub

Comment: You assign a sheet with name `START` to `shtDest`. Later you check if the name of that sheet has the pattern `"*-*"` (basically checking for a hyphen within the name). As this is never true, nothing is happening. Get familiar with the VBA debugger and execute the code step by step (F8) to see where it behaves different than expected.

Comment: Ah im blind, thank you.